# Generate aggregated Json data from Json string in java

Tags: java, sql, json, db2, aggregate

I have fetched below JSON string from db2, need to perform grouping on data.

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAY(JSON_OBJECT('id' VALUE id,
                   'items' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
                                                          'itemScore' value itemScore,
                                                          'stage' value stage,
                                                          'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                                                         'url' value url,
                                                                         'score' value score
                                                                         format json)format json absent on null)
                   format json absent on null)format json absent on null)
FROM Product
GROUP BY id, item, itemScore, stage, url, product, score
```

It will help if there is a solution in Java or DB2 query.

Need to perform grouping on JSON string by using id.

JSON String:

```
[{
    "id": 2078012,
    "items": {
        "item": "cos",
        "itemScore": -0.1334,
        "stage": 0.5,
        "reco": {
            "product": "Language",
            "url": "https://",
            "score": 0.019
        }
    }
},
{
    "id": 2078012,
    "items": {
        "item": "build",
        "itemScore": -0.2858,
        "stage": 0.5,
        "reco": {
            "product": "Notifications",
            "url": "https://",
            "score": 0.0169
        }
    }
}]
```

Expected output:
Need to group items by using ID

I have modified the expected JSON, Please help me creating the updated JSON.

```
[{
    "id": 2078012,
    "items": {
        "item": "cos",
        "itemScore": -0.1334,
        "stage": 0.5,
        "reco": [{
            "product": "Language",
            "url": "https://",
            "score": 0.019
        },
        {
            "product": "Notifications",
            "url": "https://",
            "score": 0.0169
        }]
    },
    "items": {
        "item": "build",
        "itemScore": -0.2858,
        "stage": 0.5,
        "reco": [{
            "product": "Language",
            "url": "https://",
            "score": 0.019
        },
        {
            "product": "Notifications",
            "url": "https://",
            "score": 0.0169
        }]
    }
}]
```

Comment: sure you want the output like that ?  'items'  are repeated in  your desired,  without array notation... Shoudn't it be `{ "id" : value , "items": [ { "item": ...} , { "item": ... } ] }` instead ?

Comment: @Samuel Pizarro, There is a correction in the JSON, { "id" : value , "items": [ { "item": ..., "reco": [{ "url":.....}]} , { "item": ..., "reco": [{ "url":.....}] } ] }, Could you please help me creating this JSON.

Comment: really ?  I have answered your original question properly.  and now you devoted my answer because you asked it wrongly !?  hehehe  you might be kidding ... I gave all the tools you need to solve either your original problem and your new one.  it's not different. You should not change your question,  after you have accepted a valid answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You may need break it in some few steps.

First,  a base table that is similar to yours.

```
db2 => SELECT * FROM PROD_T

ID          ITEM                 ITEMSCORE STAGE PRODUCT              URL                  SCORE
----------- -------------------- --------- ----- -------------------- -------------------- -------
    2078012 cos                    -0,1334   0,5 Language             https://              0,0190
    2078012 build                  -0,2585   0,5 Notification         https://              0,1690
    2100000 alpha                  -0,1334   0,5 Letter               https://              0,0190
    2100000 beta                   -0,2585   0,5 anouncement          https://              0,1690
```

**Step 1: Create the base level json objects**

```
select id, item, 
  JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
               'itemScore' value itemScore,
               'stage' value stage,
               'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                        'url' value url ,
                                        'score' value score 
                                        FORMAT JSON ) 
                FORMAT JSON ABSENT ON NULL  
               RETURNING VARCHAR(200) FORMAT JSON) ITEM_JSON  
FROM PROD_T 

ID          ITEM                 ITEM_JSON
----------- -------------------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    2078012 cos                  {"item":"cos","itemScore":-0.1334,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Language","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.0190}}
    2078012 build                {"item":"build","itemScore":-0.2585,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Notification","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.1690}}
    2100000 alpha                {"item":"alpha","itemScore":-0.1334,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Letter","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.0190}}
    2100000 beta                 {"item":"beta","itemScore":-0.2585,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"anouncement","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.1690}}
```

**Step 2: group by id, and agregate the objects in a array.**

```
WITH BASE AS ( 
select id, item, 
  JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
               'itemScore' value itemScore,
               'stage' value stage,
               'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                        'url' value url ,
                                        'score' value score 
                                        FORMAT JSON ) 
                FORMAT JSON ABSENT ON NULL  
               RETURNING VARCHAR(200) FORMAT JSON) ITEM_JSON  
FROM PROD_T  ) 
 SELECT ID, JSON_ARRAY ( LISTAGG( ITEM_JSON , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ITEM) FORMAT JSON ) ITEMS_ARRAY
 FROM BASE GROUP BY ID 


ID          ITEMS_ARRAY
----------- --------------------------------------------------
    2078012 [{"item":"build","itemScore":-0.2585,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Notification","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.1690}}, {"item":"cos","itemScore":-0.1334,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Language","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.0190}}] 
    2100000 [{"item":"alpha","itemScore":-0.1334,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Letter","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.0190}}, {"item":"beta","itemScore":-0.2585,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"anouncement","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.1690}}]
```

**Step 3: Create the entire json_object for each id row**

```
WITH BASE AS ( 
select id, item, 
  JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
               'itemScore' value itemScore,
               'stage' value stage,
               'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                        'url' value url ,
                                        'score' value score 
                                        FORMAT JSON ) 
                FORMAT JSON ABSENT ON NULL  
               RETURNING VARCHAR(200) FORMAT JSON) ITEM_JSON  
FROM PROD_T  ) 
 SELECT JSON_OBJECT ( KEY 'id' VALUE ID , 
            KEY 'itens' VALUE 
                   JSON_ARRAY ( LISTAGG( ITEM_JSON , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ITEM) FORMAT JSON ) 
            FORMAT JSON ) json_objects 
 FROM BASE GROUP BY ID 


json_objects 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"id":2078012,"itens":[{"item":"build","itemScore":-0.2585,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Notification","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.1690}}, {"item":"cos","itemScore":-0.1334,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Language","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.0190}}]} 
{"id":2100000,"itens":[{"item":"alpha","itemScore":-0.1334,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"Letter","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.0190}}, {"item":"beta","itemScore":-0.2585,"stage":0.5,"reco":{"product":"anouncement","url":"https:\/\/","score":0.1690}}]}
```

**Step 4: Full json doc array of ids**

Bellow query should work,

```
WITH BASE AS ( 
select id, item, 
  JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
               'itemScore' value itemScore,
               'stage' value stage,
               'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                        'url' value url ,
                                        'score' value score 
                                        FORMAT JSON ) 
                FORMAT JSON ABSENT ON NULL  
               RETURNING VARCHAR(200) FORMAT JSON) ITEM_JSON  
FROM PROD_T  ),  
 PROD_OBJS AS ( 
     SELECT  JSON_OBJECT ( KEY 'id' VALUE ID , 
            KEY 'itens' VALUE 
                   JSON_ARRAY ( LISTAGG( ITEM_JSON , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ITEM) FORMAT JSON ) 
            FORMAT JSON ) json_objects 
     FROM BASE GROUP BY ID ) 
SELECT JSON_ARRAY (select json_objects FROM PROD_OBJS format json) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

but, in my system ( DB2 v11.5.0.1077 ) , its failing with some internal compilation error:

> SQL0901N  The SQL statement or command failed because of a database
> system error. (Reason "Unexpected agg opparm".)  SQLSTATE=58004

But,  if the same happens to you, you can materialize the output from step3 in a temporary table,  and execute the final array from it.

```
DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE prod_json_objcts AS ( 
WITH BASE AS ( 
select id, item, 
  JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
               'itemScore' value itemScore,
               'stage' value stage,
               'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                        'url' value url ,
                                        'score' value score 
                                        FORMAT JSON ) 
                FORMAT JSON ABSENT ON NULL  
               RETURNING VARCHAR(200) FORMAT JSON) ITEM_JSON  
FROM PROD_T  ) 
 SELECT JSON_OBJECT ( KEY 'id' VALUE ID , 
            KEY 'itens' VALUE 
                   JSON_ARRAY ( LISTAGG( ITEM_JSON , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ITEM) FORMAT JSON ) 
            FORMAT JSON ) json_objects 
 FROM BASE GROUP BY ID 
) WITH DATA 

SELECT JSON_ARRAY (select json_objects FROM session.prod_json_objcts format json) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Produces the final json array :

```
[{"id":2078012,
  "itens":[
      {"item":"build",
       "itemScore":-0.2585,
       "stage":0.5,
       "reco":{"product":"Notification",
               "url":"https:\/\/",
               "score":0.1690}}, 
      {"item":"cos",
       "itemScore":-0.1334,
       "stage":0.5,
       "reco":{"product":"Language",
               "url":"https:\/\/",
               "score":0.0190}}
    ]
 },
 {"id":2100000,
  "itens":[
      {"item":"alpha",
       "itemScore":-0.1334,
       "stage":0.5,
       "reco":{"product":"Letter",
               "url":"https:\/\/",
               "score":0.0190}}, 
        {"item":"beta",
         "itemScore":-0.2585,
         "stage":0.5,
         "reco":{"product":"anouncement",
                 "url":"https:\/\/",
                 "score":0.1690}}
    ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Samuel Pizarro Thank You So much for this answer, it's working.