# DB2 select JSON_ARRAYAGG

Tags: db2

Using of JSON_ARRAYAGG does not working for me

```
1) [Code: -104, SQL State: 42601]  An unexpected token "ORDER" was found following "CITY)
".  Expected tokens may include:  ")".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11
2) [Code: -727, SQL State: 56098]  An error occurred during implicit system action type "2". Information returned for the error includes SQLCODE "-104", SQLSTATE "42601" and message tokens "ORDER|CITY)
|)".. SQLCODE=-727, SQLSTATE=56098, DRIVER=4.28.11
```

I want an output like this

```
{"id":901, "name": "Hansi", "addresses" : 
 [
   { "address":"A", "city":"B"}, 
   { "address":"C", "city":"D"}
  ]
}
```

I am using IBM DB2 11.1 for Linux, UNIX and Windows.

```
  values (
    json_array(
    select json_object ('ID' value ID,
                        'NAME' value NAME,
       'ADDRESSES' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                                  JSON_OBJECT('ADDRESS' VALUE ADDRESS,
                                  'CITY' VALUE CITY)
                                  ORDER BY ADDRESS)
     )
    FROM CUSTOMER
    JOIN CUSTOMER_ADDRESS ON ADDRESS_CUSTOMER_ID = ID
    GROUP BY ID, NAME
    FORMAT JSON
    ));
```

Used tables are:

```
CUSTOMER - ID (INT), NAME (VARCHAR64)
ADDRESS - ADDRESS (VARCHAR64), CITY (VARCHAR64)
```

Comment: add details on your tables: what columns and types

Comment: What's the Db2 platform and version?

Comment: JSON_ARRAYAGG is not a supported function in Db2 for Linux, UNIX, Windows

Comment: What will be an alternative to build up the same output.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64497336/generate-aggregated-json-data-from-json-string-in-java